# Doctrine - How to add fields to the primary key in an extended entity?

Tags: sql, database, symfony, doctrine, primary-key

I'm extending an entity with Doctrine in a Symfony project.
The field that I want to add goes like this

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="chiave_totale", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $chiave_totale;
```

As you see I want this field in the extended entity to be part of the composed primary key of the table. Doctrine however doesn't seem to read the `@ORM\Id` part of my annotation, so how can I do this?

UPDATE

This is the parent class

```
    /**
 * ERP_Partite
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="erp_partite")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ERP_PartiteRepository")
 *
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 */
class ERP_Partite
{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="progressivo_partita", type="string", length=30)
     */
    public $progressivo_partita;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="progressivo_scadenza", type="string", length=30)
     */
    public $progressivo_scadenza;
}
```

Comment: What does "composed primary key" means here? You want to create a PK based on entity key you're extending and this key?

Comment: Yes, exactly this

Comment: Please, show both classes, thanks

Comment: here you are...